# How to pull docker image using id?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster

I have created a docker image using the following command:

```
./gradlew bootWar -Pprod buildDocker
```

And it returned me an id: `Created image with ID '123xxx123'`

Following this guide: https://www.jhipster.tech/documentation-archive/v4.5.3/docker-compose/#3
I was able to run the image using `sudo docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up` on my local machine. (Although I don't think it was using the image because there was no mention of the generated id in the app.yml file.)

Now I want to run the same image on a remote server (where I don't have the files locally obviously). How can I do that? I tried `docker-compose -f app.yml up`, with app.yml having `image: 123xxx123`, but I get the error:

> pull access denied for 49f2b30f485c, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Any help or direction to a guide/tutorial is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you get this working

Answer (score -1):

You need to push the image to to your docker registry.

**On local marching run:**
`docker push [IMAGE_NAME:TAG]`

**On remote server Run**

`docker login`

Enter creds for docker registry.

Then run

`docker-compose -f app.yml up`

**Note:**
You will need at least the yaml file on the remote server to run the container. Depending on app structure you may need more but minimum the yaml file is required.